# Cordova unable to post data to server using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I am developing a `Phonegap Cordova` application and I want to `POST` data to server using `AJAX` but am not able to, am getting an error.

My example code is:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

        $('#frm').submit(function()
    {

    var username = $('#textinput').val();
    var username = $.trim(username);
    var password = $('#passwordinput').val();
    var password = $.trim(password);

    {

        alert('Please enter username');
        return false;

    }
    else if(password =='')
    {
        alert('Please enter password');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var user = $('[name=username]').val();
        var pass = $('[name=password]').val();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://eqfree***p.com/log_sb.php',
        rossDomain: true,
        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
        complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
        data: { username:'user', password:'pass'},  
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.success);
            alert('success');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');

        }
    });
 return false;
    }
});
        });
          </script>
```

Comment: What's the error? Check out the whitelist plugin for external requests: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: Cleanup of intro text.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $('#frm').submit(function()
  {

  var username = $('#textinput').val();
  var username = $.trim(username);
  var password = $('#passwordinput').val();
  var password = $.trim(password);

  else if(username =='')//check condition
  {

    alert('Please enter username');
    return false;

  }
  else if(password =='')
  {
    alert('Please enter password');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    //no need to re initialize
    //var user = $('[name=username]').val();
    //var pass = $('[name=password]').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://eqfree***p.com/log_sb.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
    complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
    data: { 'username':username, 'password':password},  
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data.success);
      alert('success');

    },
    error: function(){
      alert('error!');

      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to update from `rossDomain: true,` to `crossDomain: true,`

Comment: I have updated but ,no improvement, still getting same error..,

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://eqfreepp.com/msgboard.php?id=Mw==. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I resolved above error but now showing GET file:///C:/Users/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: if debug app in chrome then add extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en
and add whitelist plugin

Comment: I am able to post data to server and i am debugging on chrome it's getting 302 but am getting error on ajax calling